# How to see the Objective-C names for Swift functions

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

Is there a way for me to see the Objective-C translated names for all Swift functions in a file in Xcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C code imports Swift by including an auto-generated
header file which contains the Objective-C interface of all (Objective-C
visible) Swift classes and methods:

```swift
#import "<ProductModuleName>-Swift.h"
```

To view the contents of this file:

- Command-click on `"<ProductModuleName>-Swift.h"` in the Xcode
  source file editor,
- choose "Jump to Definition".